# How to add edge color to a histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

While doing some practice problems using seaborn and a Jupyter notebook, I realized that the distplot() graphs did not have the darker outlines on the individual bins that all of the sample graphs in the documentation have.  I tried creating the graphs using Pycharm and noticed the same thing.  Thinking it was a seaborn problem, I tried some hist() charts using matplotlib, only to get the same results.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
plt.hist(titanic['fare'], bins=30)
```

yielded the following graph:

[image]

Finally I stumbled across the 'edgecolor' parameter on the plt.hist() function, and setting it to black did the trick.  Unfortunately I haven't found a similar parameter to use on the seaborn distplot() function, so I am still unable to get a chart that looks like it should.

I looked into changing the rcParams in matplotlib, but I have no experience with that and the following script I ran seemed to do nothing:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 1
mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'black'
mpl.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 1
mpl.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'black'
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 1
mpl.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = 'black'
```

I was just kind of guessing at the value I was supposed to change, but running my graphs again showed no changes.

I then attempted to go back to the default settings using mpl.rcdefaults()
but once again, no change.

I reinstalled matplotlib using conda but still the graphs look the same.  I am running out of ideas on how to change the default edge color for these charts.  I am running the latest versions of Python, matplotlib, and seaborn using the Conda build.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

- As part of the update to matplotlib 2.0 the edges on bar plots are [turned off by default](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/users/dflt_style_changes.html#patch-edges-and-color). However, this behavior can be globally changed with `rcParams`.

  - `plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True`
- Alternatively, set the `edgecolor` / `ec` parameter in the plot call, and potentially increase the `linewidth` / `lw` parameter.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.0.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

### Imports and Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2023)  # ensures the data is repeatable
x = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=x, columns=['values'])

# precalculate the histogram values to plot a bar plot
counts, bins = np.histogram(x)
```

### pandas

- Uses [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) as the default plotting backend.

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='hist', ec='k')
```

### matplotlib

#### `.hist`

```py
plt.hist(x, ec="k")
```

#### `.bar`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=range(len(counts)), height=counts, width=1, ec='k')

# sets the bin values at the bar edges
_ = ax.set_xticks(ticks=np.arange(0, len(bins)) - 0.5, labels=bins.round(2))
```

### seaborn

- Is a high-level API for [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib).
- [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)
- `ec='k'` is the default setting. However, `ec` can be used to set a different color or `None`.

#### `.histplot`

- An axes-level function.

```py
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='values')
```

#### `.displot`

- A figure-level function.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, kind='hist', x='values')
```

#### `.distplot`

- Replaced by `histplot` and `displot`.
- Set the edgecolor when creating a `distplot`, using the `hist_kws` argument.

```py
ax = sns.distplot(x, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="k", linewidth=2))
```

### Example Plot

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As of Mar, 2021 :

```
sns.histplot(data, edgecolor='k', linewidth=2)
```

work.
Using `hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="k", linewidth=2)` gave an error:
`AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no property 'hist_kws'`