# matplotlib changed rendering style unexpectedly in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

My matplotlib plots have changed styles unexpectedly. I am trying to pin down what I did to change them. My best guess is that I changed matplotlib versions, or I'm possibly am using a different backend.

A histogram plot currently looks like this:

[image: Current plot style]

They used to look like this (nice defined border lines between the bars):

[image]

I have made no changes to the code that generates the plots, but I have mucked with import statements, and re-installed various components of anaconda, including matplotlib for unrelated reasons.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080259/no-outlines-on-bins-of-matplotlib-histograms-or-seaborn-distplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier this year, matplotlib changed their defaults. You want the edgecolor param.

```
plt.hist(np.random.norma(0,1,100), edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

You can use a classic style by passing `plt.style.use('classic')`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from matplotlib version 2.0, patches do not have edges anymore. See the [Changes to the default style](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html#patch-edges-and-color).

Options to set edges back on:

1. Use the `edgecolor` argument of the artist. E.g.

   ```
   plt.bar(...., edgecolor="k")
   ```
2. Use the [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to globally set edges,

   ```
   plt.rcParams['patch.force_edgecolor'] = True
   ```

   or edit you matplotlibrc file accordingly.
3. Turn the old style on again, using

   ```
   plt.style.use('classic')
   ```