# How to use hist_kws in seaborn displot

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

I want to plot histogram and kde line in the same plot with different color. I want to set green color for the histogram and blue color for the kde line. I managed to figure out using line_kws to change the kde line color but hist_kws is not working on the displot. I have tried using histplot but I am unable to put different color for the hist and the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `line_kws={'color': ...}` to change the color of the kde line. And directly `facecolor=...` to change the color of the histogram.
The following code has been tested with seaborn 0.11.1 and `displot` with the default `kind` (`kind='hist')` and no `hue`:

- `sns.displot(..., facecolor=...)` changes the color of the histogram faces
- `sns.displot(..., edgecolor=...)` changes the color of the histogram edges
- `sns.displot(..., color=...)` changes the color of the kde line (when `kde=True`)
- `sns.displot(..., line_kws={'lw':...})` changes the parameters of the kdeline, except the color

Here is an example:

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.displot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True, col="species", color='red',
            line_kws={'lw': 3}, facecolor='lime', edgecolor='black')
```

[image: displot, set color for histogram]

Seaborn's forte is the `hue` parameter, placing multiple distributions together, for which it is very handy that corresponding kde and histogram get the same color. When using `hue`, the above coloring gets overridden.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Johan. It works. May I know how do you figure it out? The arguments are not mentioned in sns documentation. I'm new to programming and I am aspire to be data scientist.

Comment: Seaborn creates some kind of chain with its parameters. `displot` names these `kwargs` ("keyword arguments") and says *Other keyword arguments are documented with the relevant axes-level function*. In this case they are sent to `histplot`, which in its turn sends `kwargs` to a.o. `plt.bar`.

Comment: @JohanC in which seaborn version you implemented the above code. I am using google colab and only facing issues regarding - changing the color of `kde` line. Line width etc everything working but only color is not changing. Please see this ![image](https://i.imgur.com/LtDvhpO.png) . Have tried so many different colors !

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora  It's unclear to me what went wrong. I updated the answer with code tested with seaborn 0.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

hist_kws is an optional argument in distplot which takes only values in a dictionary. You can use this to set linewidth, edgecolor etc.
[Example for your ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzK6.png)